# Angular is showing an empty array when consuming a JSON api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, angularjs

I'm having trouble using a Rails JSON API in my angular app.  I created a service in Angular that does this is querying my rails database for the index with code like this:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp');

app.factory('Comment', function($resource) {
    return $resource('http://localhost:3000/comments.json', {},{
      index: { method: 'GET', isArray: true, responseType: 'json' },
      show: { method: 'GET', responseType: 'json' },
      update: { method: 'PUT', responseType: 'json' }
    });
  });


app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, Comment) {
    $scope.json = Comment.index();
  });
```

My Rails controller code looks like this:

```
  def index
    @comments = Comment.all

    render json: @comments
  end
```

My routes file is just:

```
resources :comments
```

And I know that my Angular App is pinging my rails API for the information because when I start the server my rails console says:

```
Started GET "/comments.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-29 20:36:16 -0700
Processing by CommentsController#index as JSON
Comment Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments"
Completed 200 OK in 2ms (Views: 2.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
```

But it just returns an empty array when I bind `$scope.json` in my HTML file.

Comment: Change your url to "/comments" instead of "/comments.json". Your rails app is responding to "/comments" directly. You can also check the browser by going to "/comments" and "/comments.json" and see what they return.

Comment: Agree with above statements, use POSTMan or curl or Firebug or the network panel in the browser (F12) to debug network requests to understand the results in a raw format and to be able to "test" your service layer separately.

Comment: I actually resolved this issue myself.

I changed my routes file to put the resources under the :api namespace.  I had tried that before, but then I made my controller class part of the Api module and physically moved the controller file into an api folder under my controller folder.  This finally properly exposed my json output to my angular controller.

Thanks for your guyses responses.